# How to improve readability of a TestCase with lots of parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

It's a mostly conceptual question. I have some class representing algorithm removing text from a (custom) TextArea control. I'd like to test it - the algorithm of course ;). I'm concerned with the lack of readability of my test method:

```
[TestCase(new[] { "some text asdf" }, 5, 0, 9, 0, "some  asdf", new int[0])]
[TestCase(new[] { "some text", "", "totally unimportant texttext that stays" }, 0, 0, 24, 2, "text that stays", new[] { 0, 1, 2 })]
public void ShouldRemoveSelectedText(string[] lines, int colStart, int lineStart, int colEnd, int lineEnd, string notRemovedText, int[] expectedRemovedLines) {
    var newLines = algorithm.RemoveLines(lines, new TextPositionsPair {
        StartPosition = new TextPosition(column: colStart, line: lineStart),
        EndPosition = new TextPosition(column: colEnd, line: lineEnd)
    });

    Assert.That(newLines.LinesToChange.First().Value, Is.EqualTo(notRemovedText));
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedRemovedLines, newLines.LinesToRemove.OrderBy(key => key));
}
```

As you can see it's a pretty simple test. I provide the algorithm with `IEnumerable` of `string` and selection area, however it's difficult to see - at first glance - which `TestCase` parameter goes where. I was wondering - is there a "cleaner" way of doing this?
Sidenote: I have tests that are as simple as this one, but must be provided with even more parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple approach is to just use more lines per case...

```
[TestCase(new [] { "some text asdf" },
          5, 0, 9, 0,
          "some  asdf",
          new int[0])]
[TestCase(new [] { "some text", "", "totally unimportant texttext that stays" },
          0, 0, 24, 2,
          "text that stays",
          new [] {0, 1, 2})]
public void ShouldRemoveSelectedText(...
```

Alternatively, you might use TestCaseSource, referring to a static array in your fixture class...

```
TestCaseData[] MySource = {
    new TestCaseData(new [] { "some text asdf" },
                     5, 0, 9, 0,
                     "some  asdf",
                     new int[0]),
    new TestCaseData(new [] { "some text", "", "totally unimportant texttext that stays" },
                     0, 0, 24, 2
                     "text that stays",
                     new [] { 0, 1, 2})};

[TestCaseSource("MySource")]
public void ShouldRemoveSelectedText(..
```

Those are the best options I can see without changing the arguments to your test, which is what I would actually do if it were my code.

I'd create an object that encapsulates a text buffer and another for a selection. I'm showing classes here, but they might be structs...

```
class TextBuffer
{
    public string[] Lines;
    public Selection Selection;
    ...
}

class Selection
{
    public int FromLine;
    public int FromCol;
    public int ToLine;
    public int ToCol;
    ...
}
```

Then I'd rewrite the test in terms of those test primitives, making it all a lot easier to read.